# Counting Arrays with Speciific Value

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

A custom Meta field in wordpress and the following code displays all the id's for the the custom meta field.

PHP

```
<?php

        $args = array( 'post_type' => 'todo_listing', 'posts_per_page' => 3,'order'=>'ASC' );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        $_meta_val_arr=array(10=>"All Item",0=>"Cat0",
            1=> "Cat1",
            2=>"Cat2",

?>      

<?php
   while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
?>
<?php echo get_the_ID();?> 
<?php
        endwhile;
?>
```

I just want to count the number of Id's with array value of Zero.e.g the count for the following with array value zero would be would be 2

[1012] => Array ( [0] => 1 ) [1013] => Array ( [0] => 0 ) [1014] => Array ( [0] => 0 )

Answer (score -1):

Just use a for loop

```
$count =0;
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($_meta_val_arry);$i++)
{
if($_meta_val_arry[$i] == '0')
{
count++;
}

}
```

Edit:

I didn't see you had an array of arrays: Try this: fixed typo

```
    $count =0;
    foreach($outarray as $innerArr)
    {
   //search through values for 0
    foreach($innerArr as $key=>$val)
    if($val=='0')
    {
    $count++;
    }

    }
    }
```

Comment: His arrays contain only one key which is [0], going through them with [$i] will produce an undefined offset